# Route to WPF image Resources

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm developing an aplication with the same icon at the main window and taskbar.

So, I added the icon to the Resources list and linked to the main window:

```
<Window x:Class="MGWUpdater.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:xxxxxx"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="xxxxxx" Height="283.333" Width="260" 
    ResizeMode="CanMinimize" Icon="Resources/icon.ico">
```

Then I created a `NotifyIcon` by this way:

```
public NotifyIcon ni = new NotifyIcon();
```

But I don't know how to assign my Icon to the `NotifyIcon` I just created. I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
ni.Icon = new Icon("Resources/icon.ico");
```

Comment: is there any error msg??

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514687(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Yes, the code I posted throws the next error msg: `Exception 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in PresentationFramework.dll`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching a while, I reach a solution. To reference any resource on your `Resources` library, you simply need to use the next code:
`Properties.Resources.your_resource`

As an example, in my code, I simply use the next line of code:

```
ni.Icon = Properties.Resources.icon;
```

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

You must add your Icon to the Resource list.Then you must add using for your Properties project to your XAML file:

```
 xmlns:res="clr-namespace:nameProject.Properties">
```

Of course if the icon is saved in a resource file, you must convert the icon. You only need to add a Convert Class in XAML code:

```
  <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <conv:ImageConverter x:Key="ImageConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

You can Bind the resource element , Image, whatever:

```
 <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Source="{Binding Source={x:Static res:Resources.close},
        Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}"/>
```

This is the ImageConverter convert class (you must add it for Binding):

```
 public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        ((System.Drawing.Bitmap)value).Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
        image.BeginInit();
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        image.StreamSource = ms;
        image.EndInit();

        return image;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Information for you: [x:Static](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [Converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I hove this help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(
        "<project namespace>.<folder path>" + "filename.ico"))
    {
        notifyIcon.Icon = new Icon(stream);
    }
```

or alternatively

```
public NotifyIcon ni = new NotifyIcon();
ni.Icon = (Icon)this.FindResource("icon.ico");
```

Comment: When I use the `ni.Icon = (Icon)this.FindResource("favicon.ico");` line of code VS throws me the next error:

`Resource 'icon.ico' not found`

BTW if I use the next line of code: `ni.Icon = (Icon)this.Resources["icon.ico"];` it starts the application, but don't show the icon on the taskbar.